# PeripheralManager force disconnection

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I have developed a peripheral connection for both Android and iOS apps. Connection and communication are working but I still have the last requirement: I need to be able to disconnect all connected centrals from the peripheral (to release the connection for another peripheral device).

On the Android side this code seems to do the job (at least when I debug using the nRF Connect app the connection is properly reset) :

```
        mBluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT).forEach {
            mGattServer?.cancelConnection(it)
        }
        mGattServer?.close()
        mGattServer?.clearServices()
```

I'm looking for the equivalent for iOS.
The only method for disconnect seems to be `cancelPeripheralConnection()` but is only available from `centralManager`.

If you have any solution it would help a lot.
Thank you

Comment: It's unclear why `centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)` wouldn't work in your case. This is a standard way.

Comment: @KirilS. because my app is the peripheral, not the central so I dont have centralManager in my code, only peripheralManager. (It's an other device who is the central and connect to my app)

Comment: In that case you "(in order to release the connection for another peripheral device)" comment doesn't make a lot of sense. Centrals connect to peripherals. The central can connect to as many peripherals as it likes. What do you envision "closing" the connection from the peripheral's side to mean? (What Bluetooth network packet do you expect to be sent?) If you don't want to respond to a central anymore, don't respond in `didReceiveRead:` or `didReceiveWrite:`. It's up to you whether to respond; but the central can still send requests.

Comment: The important call is `clearServices()`, which is equivalent to `removeAllServices()` in iOS. This says to stop advertising the service to anyone.

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you for your reply, unfortunately the manufacturer design the product to connect to only one peripheral at a time... That's why I'm trying to cancel the connection from the peripheral in order to force the device to scan and connect to the next one... So if I well understand, I'm stuck with that ?

Comment: @JulienMobileDev Did you ever find a way to disconnect from the peripheral side?

Answer (score 0):

Is this u want?

```
peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [serviceUUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: deviceName])

peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, what I want is cancel all incoming connection to me (as peripheral). Android provide a method BluetoothGattServer.cancelConnection(BluetoothDevice), I'm looking for the equivalent in iOS.

Comment: I need this too. I've been searching, but haven't found a solution either. I'll be back if I find a way.